# How to replace digits in 1 column in dataframe inplace?

Tags: python, pandas

The df has some 200000 rows. One column is telephone number. I need to replace 8 with +7. I dont want to create another df. I want to do it inplace.

```
df.head()

client_id   contact_number  
0           +77760013505    
1           +77779261433    
2           +77071061047    
3           +77714032401    
4            87787763621    
5            87787763621
```

I want to replace those with 8 to +7 inplace.

```
starts_8_length_11 = df[(df['contact_number'].str.startswith('8')) & (df['contact_number'].str.len()==11)]
```

But I dont want to create starts8_length11  from the main df, change it then put it back into the df. How to do it inplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution should be replace `8` with regex `^` for start of string, but only for rows with lenght `11`:

```
m = (df['contact_number'].str.len()==11)

df.loc[m, 'contact_number'] = df.loc[m, 'contact_number'].str.replace('^8', '+7')
print (df)
  client_id contact_number
0         0   +77760013505
1         1   +77779261433
2         2   +77071061047
3         3   +77714032401
4         4   +77787763621
5         5   +77787763621
```

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: why ^8? what is ^8?

Comment: Regular expression. ^8 is the digit 8 at the beginning of the string if I recall correctly.